How to send HTTP Post request in C# without JSON content
So I need to sent an HTTP Post request in C# (.NET) without JSON parameters because they are already in message.SentUrl (That's just how my boss wants me to do it) and if the response is 200 return true, else return false. Is there any way I can do it without making my function async?
public static bool SendMessage(SpoolMessage message)    
{
    message.SentUrl = ReplaceUrlParameters(message);
 
    // Make post request here and return true if success else return false
 
}


Then it's a GET request more rather a POST

You can still invoke the async method PostAsync synchronously like so -
If you do not want to pass any data then just pass null instead of content-
public static bool SendMessage(SpoolMessage message)     {     message.SentUrl = ReplaceUrlParameters(message);     // Make post request here and return true if success else return false      HttpClient client = new HttpClient();       client.BaseAddress = new Uri("you address with data");      var response = client.PostAsync(url, null).GetAwaiter().GetResult(); }

@kode_anil That code is terrible: no usings to dispose, and use of sync-over-async with .GetResult which should never ever be used.
